# Firebase linking Anonymous user to Email Link user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I would like to create an anonymous user account for visitors to the app to collect some basic info via forms and then prompt them to create an account via Email Link Authentication (no password) later.

I am using the JavaScript SDK and [this is the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking#link-email-address-and-password-credentials-to-a-user-account) to the documentation

The goal is to link these two accounts. I am getting an "Unknown provider" error when trying to do this. The docs do not specify whether or not this is possible and there is no example. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share the code and screenshot of the error?

Comment: Well I figured it out. Though it's not explicitly stated in the docs, generating a credential with EmailAuthProvider.credentialWithLink then invoking linkWithCredential seems to do the trick. :)